# ComboBox will not update its display list unless you change selections first

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

Update: I checked the answer before I fully tested it still does not work. I updated the code below so you should just be able to paste in to a empty WinForms project and it should compile.

UPDATE:
I have found that if I change the selected item on the ComboBox to any other item, it now behaves as expected (in my code below I would switch from test1 to test2). As I have not received any answers yet, I change the question to this.

Why do I have to change to a different item in the combo box before it will show the changes I make to the underlying data-source?

Here is  a quick test case of what is happening.

1. Change `test1` to `test1asdf` text in txtBroken
2. click off to commit change
3. text in combo box does not update.
4. Change combo box to test2
5. change `test2` to `test2asdf` text in txtBroken
6. click off to commit change
7. text in combo box immediately shows 'test2asdf' still displays `test1` for first item in the drop-down
8. change to `test1`
9. combo box displays `test1` text box displays `test1asdf`
10. update text box to `test1asd`
11. combo box immediately displays `test1asd`

Other than behind the scenes changing the selected item on load and changing it back (this seems like such a hack) how can I fix this?

---

I have a combo box databound to a `BindingSource` bound to a `List<Holder>` it has `Holder.Name` as its display value. I also have a text box bound to `Holder.Name` but if I change the text in the text box it will not change what is displayed in the combo box. Changing selected items and changing back will show the updated text in the text box, but will still have the old value displayed in the combo box. How do I make the item in the combo box update?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sandbox_Form
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lstBroken = new BindingList<Holder>();
            lstBroken.Add(new Holder("test1"));
            lstBroken.Add(new Holder("test2"));
            bsBroken = new BindingSource(lstBroken, null);
            cmbBroken.DataSource = bsBroken;
            cmbBroken.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmbBroken.SelectedIndex = 0;
            txtBroken.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsBroken, "Name");
            txtBroken.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtBroken_TextChanged);

        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        void txtBroken_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((Control)sender).FindForm().Validate();
        }
        private BindingSource bsBroken;
        private BindingList<Holder> lstBroken;
        private ComboBox cmbBroken;
        private TextBox txtBroken;
        private Label label1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.cmbBroken = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.txtBroken = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // cmbBroken
            // 
            this.cmbBroken.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.cmbBroken.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cmbBroken.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 32);
            this.cmbBroken.Name = "cmbBroken";
            this.cmbBroken.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 21);
            this.cmbBroken.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // txtBroken
            // 
            this.txtBroken.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 60);
            this.txtBroken.Name = "txtBroken";
            this.txtBroken.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 20);
            this.txtBroken.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label1.Text = "Broken";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtBroken);
            this.Controls.Add(this.cmbBroken);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private void cmbWorks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    public class Holder
    {
        public Holder(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        private string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I bind to a `List<String>` instead using `Holder.Name` it works as expected (this is just a simple mock-up, the real class has more than just a name so a list of strings will not work). I think this is a clue to what is wrong but I don't know what it is. Using an Observable instead of a list makes no difference.

Comment: Actually set txtBackupName datacontext to the selected item of cboJobSelector, and then bind to the Name property, as your currently only binding to the text property of the combo box. As far as i am aware combo box won't update the original source if you change its current text property.

Comment: @Scott i'm not sure how exactly to do it in code, i know how to do it xaml, but can I ask why you're using binding with winforms? and not just use WPF?

Comment: @LnDCobra Because the lead developer has a irrational hatetraed of WPF and he wants it done in winforms

Comment: The above scenario is exactly why I moved from Winforms to WPF :) Make it so much easier, all you would have to do is Text="{Binding Source=SelectedBackupJob, Path=Name}" :P

Comment: /*Bind the fourth TextBox to the Value of the 
   DateTimePicker control. This demonstrates how one control
   can be bound to another.*/
   textBox4.DataBindings.Add("Text", DateTimePicker1,"Value");
   BindingManagerBase bmText = this.BindingContext[
   DateTimePicker1];

Comment: In your case it would probably be txtBackupName.DataBinding.Add("Text", cboJobsSelector, "SelectedItem.Name"); Try that see if it works

Comment: @LnDCobra doing that throws a exception.

Comment: Whats the exception/Inner exception?

Comment: or try txtBackupName.DataBinding.Add("Text", cboJobsSelector.SelectedItem, "Name");

Comment: That gives a null refrence execption as .SelectedItem does not have items at the time of its calling.

Comment: oh dear, i give up on WinForms binding, don't have to worry about null reference exceptions in WPF :P Only thing i can think off (dirty hack) is to listen to the change event of the ComboBox, and once its changed, then bind to the SelectedItem if it is not null.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a [`BindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) instead of a `List`. It was designed to address such issues. Dinesh Chandnani, a member of the .NET Client Team, states the following in a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dchandnani/archive/2005/03/12/394438.aspx):

> `BindingList<T>` is the new generic
>   implementation of IBindingList which
>   fires ListChanged event when items are
>   added/removed/inserted/etc. from the
>   list. bindingSource hooks on to these
>   events and is thus “aware” of these
>   changes and can notify controls bound
>   thos this BindingSource.

I was able to reproduce the issue you described in your updated entry, but didn't quite reproduce the original issue without tweaking the code slightly.

By using a `BindingList<Holder>` I was able to get an immediate response when focus left the textbox. It's possible to get instant updates by using an overloaded method when adding a new data binding. I also set the `BindingSource`'s `DataSource` directly since using a `null` `dataMember` in the overloaded constructor was not yielding the expected behavior.

Here's the code I ended up with based off your sample code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingSource bs;
    private BindingList<Holder> bList;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bList = new BindingList<Holder>();
        bList.Add(new Holder("test1"));
        bList.Add(new Holder("test2"));

        bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = bList;

        cmb.DataSource = bs;
        cmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmb.ValueMember = "Name";

        // updates when focus leaves the textbox
        txt.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Name");

        // updates when the property changes
        //txt.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}
```

Comment out the first `txt` binding and uncomment the one below it to see the [`DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) in action.

Here are some `BindingList` resources:

- [BindingSource and BindingList Of T - DataBinding made simple!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dchandnani/archive/2005/03/12/394438.aspx)
- [BindingSource - A Closer Look...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dchandnani/archive/2005/03/24/396387.aspx)
- [Databinding - Bindinglist, BindingSource and BusinessObjects - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Bindinglist.aspx)
- [Databinding - BindingList, BindingSource, and BusinessObjects: Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/SearchSortBindingList.aspx)
- [Behind the Scenes: Improvements to Windows Forms Data Binding in the .NET Framework 2.0, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480736.aspx)

  ---

  **EDIT:** in reply to the issues you're facing with your updated code, please make these changes:

**1)** Replace `bsBroken = new BindingSource(lstBroken, null);` with:

```
bsBroken = new BindingSource();
bsBroken.DataSource = lstBroken;
```

Or in one line: `bsBroken = new BindingSource() { DataSource = lstBroken };`

This yields the expected behavior with an immediate response to changes (I also mentioned this before above). Do **not** use the overload that accepts a `dataMember` and set it to null. Doing so gives the buggy behavior you're experiencing.

**2)** After doing the above, I see no need for the `txtBroken_TextChanged` event. Comment out the event handler assignment to test, but you should be able to remove it completely.

Comment: I gave you the credit without fully testing it. it still behaves the same with the binding list. I will paste a fully working code sample in my subject.

Comment: @Scott I've updated my post (see the **EDIT** above) and was able to fix your problem. Update the `BindingSource.DataSource` assignment and you should be good to go.

Comment: I give the accepted answer back to you. However I am going to keep the TextChanged event because that way it will update the text in the combo box as you type instead of clicking off before the update and I prefer that visual style over waiting for you to click off.