# How can I reset a ComboBox when the underlying list changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm currently working on a WinForms graphical interface in C#. The form has a ComboBox that is displaying the contents of a custom class I wrote. This class implements the IList interface so that it can be used as the DataSource for that ComboBox.

The issue is that when I add or remove items to/from the underlying object, the ComboBox does not visually reflect this.
I have tried reassigning the list to the DataSource property whenever the contents change, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Most of the answers on this site that deal with this issue or similar seem to require a number of extra classes, or editing XAML documents, in order to achieve this.

Is there a simpler method to achieving this? If it makes a difference, the ComboBox will not be visible at the point where changes are made to the IList sourcing it. The only idea I've had so far is to possibly delete the ComboBox and replace it with a new one when needed, but I'm not sure if this is possible to do at runtime, and is obviously not very elegant either way.

Comment: have you considered IBindingList instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3603995/3424480

Comment: I had never heard of IBindingList before, but I've just made the changes to my code to use that and it appears to solve my problems, so thank you!